# How to create multiple unknown variables in function handle for fminunc

Tags: matlab

This code works well as long as the number of symbolic inputs in symEq is 2, which results in a function handle with two parameters, `x(1), x(2)`:

```
syms A   
A = sym('A', [2 1]);  
b = [1 2;3 4];  
c = [3 4];  
range = [1 1];  
symEq(A) = abs(sum(b*(A-c')));  
Eq = @(x) double(symEq(x(1), x(2)));  
[X,Y] = fminunc(Eq,range)
```

But if the symbolic input in symEq is changed to 3, it will produce an error unless I change the function handle to accept three parameters, `x(1), x(2), x(3)`.

However I need the number of parameters to be an arbitrary number, let's say 510, and the function handle to automatically have as many parameters: `x(1), x(2), ... x(510)`, without me needing to manually type the 510 unknown variables into the code.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a lot of things to be said.

First of all, why use symbolics if what you get in the end is numeric anyway? Matlab can do symbolic computations, but it excels at numerics, especially in linear algebra. Other minor things are: the value you give to `A` is not used, because `A` later only appears as a parameter, `range` is a misnomer since it's actually the intial value of `A0` for `fminunc` to find the minimum, and `Eq` is actually a function.

More importantly though, *there is no need* to refer to the elements of `x` (which is actually `A`) separately – the matrix is the natural unit for computations in Matlab.

Changing all these things gives:

```
b = [1 2; 3 4];  
c = [3 4];  
A0 = [1 1];  
fun = @(A) abs(sum(b * (A - c)'));  
[X, Y] = fminunc(fun, A0)
```

In this form, extending the code to higher dimensions is trivial: You just have to set appropriately the parameters `b` and `c` as well as the initial value `A0`. For three dimensions e.g.:

```
b = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];  
c = [3 4 5];  
A0 = [1 1 1];
fun = @(A) abs(sum(b * (A - c)'));  
[X, Y] = fminunc(fun, A0)
```

And for 510 dimensions, using randomly initialized parameters just as an example:

```
b = rand(501, 501);  
c = rand(1, 501);  
A0 = ones(1, 501);  
fun = @(A) abs(sum(b * (A - c)'));  
[X, Y] = fminunc(fun, A0)
```

---

But there's more: Minimizing the modulus of a function is equivalent to minimizing its square:

```
fun = @(A) (sum(b * (A - c)')) .^ 2;
```

This is a simple least-squares problem, and using `fminunc` for that is overkill. Moreover, in this particular case the solution found is always at a function value of 0, which is achieved if `A - c` is zero. So the whole minimization boils down to:

```
A = c;
```